# ASP File Extension Split

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic

I have the following code:

```
Public Sub Save(path)
    Dim streamFile, fileItem, filePath, allowedExtensions
    allowedExtensions = ".jpg, .gif, .png, .zip, .7z, .exe, .bmp, .pdf, .doc, .docx"

    if Right(path, 1) <> "\" then path = path & "\" '"

    if not uploadedYet then Upload

    For Each fileItem In UploadedFiles.Items        
        Dim MyArray, extension

        MyArray = Split(fileItem, ".")
        extension = MyArray(UBound(MyArray)-1)

        '' # var extension = UCase(right(fileItem.FileName,5,);

        if(allowedExtensions.Contains(extension)) then  
            filePath = path & fileItem.FileName
            Set streamFile = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            streamFile.Type = adTypeBinary
            streamFile.Open
            StreamRequest.Position=fileItem.Start
            StreamRequest.CopyTo streamFile, fileItem.Length
            streamFile.SaveToFile filePath, adSaveCreateOverWrite
            streamFile.close
            Set streamFile = Nothing
            fileItem.Path = filePath
        end if
     Next
End Sub
```

I cannot seem to get this line correct:

```
MyArray = Split(fileItem, ".")
```

The browser is telling me:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01b6'
>
> Object doesn't support this property or method
>
> /up/freeaspupload.asp, line 90

Everywhere I look up, it shows this is how you do it.

Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong or a way around this?

I just want to only allow certain extensions to be uploaded.

Comment: code is missing...where does 'UploadedFiles.Items' come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VBScript primitive types has not built-in methods. So, **allowedExtensions** cannot have `Contains` method. I think this is why the error occurred. Line `MyArray = Split(fileItem, ".")` is correct and clear.

> <s>if(allowedExtensions.Contains(extension)) then</s>

You could use [InStr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybb344c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to search a word within another.

```vb
'For case insensitive search
If InStr(1, BeingSearched, SearchedFor, vbTextCompare) Then
    'Contains
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

Well Kul-Tigin has spotted another problem with your code that you would crash into once you got past the Split problem that this question is actually about.   The reason your Split function fails I suspect is that it should look like this:

```
 MyArray = Split(fileItem.FileName, ".")
```

Note that you should probably be passing the value of the `FileName` property of the `fileItem` object.  It would seem that `fileItem` does not have a default property specified.